# What's the reason for a program to crash every time a breakpoint is set in x64dbg?

Tags: x64dbg

I know this question may be an ambiguous one and so may not be straightforward, so I apologize for that. Nevertheless, I believe that anti-debugging is responsible for the constant crashing of the program whenever the breakpoint is hit but I am not sure.

I have tried to use other debugging tools but still the same trouble I am getting. So I believe whatever is going on is specific to the way the program is working. So any ideas as to what is responsible for this and how do I go around it

Comment: Have you tried using a hardware breakpoint?

Comment: yes and it works the same thing happened

Comment: I am suspecting it has something to do with multithread but not sure